# Using a function's argument to name a column being "gathered"

Tags: r

I'm using the code below to apply various statistical functions to a data frame. That part is working; however, I want to be able to "gather" the computed statistics and give the `value` column a name that I pass into the function. The code below always labels the `value` column as `stat_name` instead of the default value `stat` or the value that I pass in. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

calc_stats <- function (data_in = combined_stock_histories, fun_to_apply, stat_name = "stat"){

 temp <- map_df(select(data_in, -Date), fun_to_apply, na.rm = TRUE)

 temp <- gather( temp, key = "ticker", value = stat_name)
}
```

Comment: See `gather_` (https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/gather_.html)

Comment: @ycw gather_ did work for me. I'm not sure I understand why from looking at the documentation, but thank you. I'm trying to mark your answer as correct, but I'm not seeing the box for me to check as stated in the instructions.

Comment: I am glad this works. I did not submit an answer, only leaving it as a comment. No need to do anything.